# Difference between RESTEasy and JAX-RS

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy

What is Resteasy? what is the difference between RESTEasy and JAX-RS?
What is the difference between `@PathParam` and `@QueryParam`?

Comment: Your last question is a duplicate [of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579744/what-is-the-difference-between-pathparam-and-queryparam).

Comment: Try to avoid asking two questions per “question” as it encourages incoherent answers; the `@PathParam` vs. `@QueryParam` question is really another question entirely.

Answer (score 22):

According to [its homepage](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy/) RESTEasy is

> ... a fully certified and portable implementation of the [JAX-RS](http://jsr311.java.net/) specification.

So JAX-RS is a specification of how a library for implementing REST APIs in Java should look like and RESTEasy is one implementation of that specification.

This effectively means that any documentation on JAX-RS should apply 1:1 to RESTEasy as well.

Answer (score 8):

**Query parameters** are extracted from the request URI query parameters, and are specified by using the javax.ws.rs.QueryParam annotation in the method parameter arguments.

Example:

```
@Path("smooth")
@GET
public Response smooth(
    @DefaultValue("2") @QueryParam("step") int step,
    @QueryParam("minm") boolean hasMin,
    @QueryParam("test") String test
    ) { ... }

URL: http://domain:port/context/XXX/smooth?step=1&minm=true&test=value
```

---

URI **path parameters** are extracted from the request URI, and the parameter names correspond to the URI path template variable names specified in the @Path class-level annotation. URI parameters are specified using the javax.ws.rs.PathParam annotation in the method parameter arguments

Example:

```
@Path("/{userName}")
public class MyResourceBean {
...
@GET
public String printUserName(@PathParam("userName") String userId) {
    ...
}
}


 URL: http://domain:port/context/XXX/naveen
```

Here, naveen takes as the userName(Path parameter)

Answer (score 7):

JAX-RS is a set of interfaces and classes without real implementation that belong to [`javax.ws.rs.*`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/package-summary.html) packages (they are part of Java SE 6, by Oracle).

[RESTEasy](https://www.jboss.org/resteasy/) as well as, for example, [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) or [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs.html), are open source implementations of that JAX-RS classes.

During compilation you need only JAX-RS. In runtime you need only one of that implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Please also note that  JAX-RS is only server side specification and RESTEasy has extended it to bring JAX-RS to the client side through the RESTEasy JAX-RS Client Framework.

Info on param,
[What is the difference between @PathParam and @QueryParam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579744/what-is-the-difference-between-pathparam-and-queryparam)
Some great points here regarding params,
[When to use @QueryParam vs @PathParam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552248/when-to-use-queryparam-vs-pathparam) - Gareth's answer

Comment: FYI: JAX-RS 2.0 includes a client-side specification.