# How to do a POST request with QueryParam

Tags: java, rest, jetty, jax-rs, jax-ws

I have a method in my rest interface which looks like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/path/{param1}/{param2}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
Response updateData(@PathParam("param1") String param1,
                       @PathParam("param2") String param2,
                       String dataPointJson);
```

I'm trying without success to do a post request, here's my code:

```
WebTarget path = collect.path("/path/someParam1/" + someParam2);
    Data dp = new Data.Builder()               
    Response post = path.request().post(Entity.json(dp));
```

Every time I get a 404 response:

```
ClientResponse{method=POST, uri=http://localhost:9090/collect/path/someParam1/someParam2, status=404, reason=Not Found}
```

Can someone please suggest what I'm doing wrong? Tried different combinations of "consumes"/"produces", also tried all examples from tutorials which I found on the net.

Comment: FYI Path parameters and Query parameters are two different things...

Comment: @RDub I would really appreciate if you could explain to a noob in ws what exactly I'm doing wrong. I don't see any difference between pathparam and queryparam in this particular example...

Comment: You may need to fix the question title (nothing in your code snippet is a query parameter): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579744/what-is-the-difference-between-pathparam-and-queryparam

Comment: As for what is going wrong, can you verify that your service is deploying successfully (to jetty?) and that it is under the /collect context? If so, can you create a simple GET endpoint and test access with a browser?

Comment: @RDub I already did that, my service is working against GET endpoint

Comment: In that case, you may need to set the media type in the request header to be JSON.

Comment: @RDub tried that before posting :(
path.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).post(Entity.json(dp))

Comment: Can you post source and configs?

Comment: Also in my previous comment I meant content type not media type... So in the POST request header the Content-Type key should have a value application/json.