# Designing restful APIs path - for returning filtered resource and for returning trimmed properties of a resource

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, spring-restcontroller

I am not asking the question that is already asked in [What is the difference between @PathParam and @QueryParam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579744/what-is-the-difference-between-pathparam-and-queryparam)

This question is related to "best practices" around restful convention.

I have a question resource with the following fields.

```
 [  
       {  
          "questionId":6,
          "area":"TECHNICAL",
          "title":"Find the index of first 1 in an infinite sorted array of 0s and 1s",
          "description":"Given an infinite sorted array consisting 0s and 1s. The problem is to find the index of first 1 in that array. As the array is infinite, therefore it is guaranteed that number 1 will be present in the array.",
          "state":"ACTIVE",
          "difficultyLevel":"EASY",
          "skills":[  
             {  
                "skillId":1,
                "skillName":"ALGORITHM"
             },
             {  
                "skillId":2,
                "skillName":"PROGRAMMING"
             }
          ],
          "proposedBy":"agrawalo",
          "noOfTimesUsed":0,
          "examples":null,
          "probes":null,
          "approvedBy":null,
          "addedBy":null,
          "dateCreated":"2018-05-16T19:29:11.113",
          "dateLastUpdated":"2018-05-16T19:29:11.113"
       }, 
       {
        ...
       },
       ...
    ]
```

I exposed a rest controller from my spring application to return all the questions using pathparam "/questions"

Now I want to design Rest URLs for following cases (basically URLs that returns filtered set of questions and urls that return part of a question object). For example:

1. return only titles of all the questions.
2. return only titles of all the technical questions.
3. return questions with skill as algorithm.

I don't think there is a standard convention of doing it. Is there? However, I would like to hear of how people design their REST APIs for use-cases like above. I would also love to hear the reason behind the practice.

Leads here is appreciated.

Comment: I voted to close this questions as there is no right or wrong in designing URIs for your API. Answers will reflect opinionated suggestions only. In a REST ecosystem it furthermore doesn't even matter how URIs are structured as clients will use meaningful relation names (like `next`, `prev`, `self`, `first` or `last`) to deduce the semantics of the URI anyway. Something like a partial resource representation should be either communicated via content negotiation or partial GET requests (though the client would already have some knoweldge here beforehand; ~ ANTI-REST)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned there is no standard way of doing this.

I would argue that these two are filters:

- return .. of all the technical questions
- return questions with skill as algorithm.

In REST filters are typically realized using query parameters. (Path parameters are used to identify resources. A filter is not a resource, so it is typically not part of the path)

This could look like this:

- `/questions?area=technical`
- `/questions?skill=algorithm`

If you require more advanced filters you could have a look into RSQL (for example: https://github.com/jirutka/rsql-parser)

To return only titles of questions one could argue that this can be a seperate title-resouces.

For example:

- `/question-titles`
- `/question-titles?area=technial`

If you use custom media types you can also define a reduced media type for this resource and request this type via the `Accept`-Header:
E.g.

`GET /questions?area=technial
Accept: application/vnd.yourapp.question.short+json`

Or you can give the caller more control using an additional query parameter:
E.g.:

- `/questions?fields=title`
- `/questions?output=reduced`

Comment: I disagree with `/questions?output=reduced`. I would suggest to use content negotiation for that and request e.g. an `InfoObject` which is reduced

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. However I am not sure what are the pros and cons of two approaches that you mentioned for fetching question title.

Comment: @HerrDerb I agree that `output=reduced` is not the best option. I also added a way using the Accept header.